# Don't break into debugger on exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

Is there any way to stop Visual Studio (2008) from breaking on an exception? I'm trying to debug some crash-handling code and I want it to do the same as it does when I'm not running in the debugger.

If I go to the "Exceptions" dialog, most of the tickboxes in the "User-handled" column aren't changeable.

Each time I hit my fake test exception, it jumps to the debugger. I can't find any way to stop this happening.

I would do it outside the debugger, but I want to hit a breakpoint in my crash-handling code.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your fake exception is handled? Visual Studio shouldn't break into the debugger unless you have it configured to break on first chance exceptions, which as far as I know, isn't the default. Are the boxes in the "User-handled" column checked?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your other comment. Try compiling in release mode and see if you can uncheck the 'user handled' exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio menus  Debug -> Exceptions -> Uncheck all in **Thrown** column.

alternatively Ctrl + Alt + E -> Uncheck all in **Thrown** column.

Comment: I want to catch unhandled exceptions. Everything in the thrown column is already unchecked. I really need to be able to uncheck everything in the "User-handled" column, but the checkboxes are readonly.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my last comment. I meant that I don't want the debugger to catch unhandled exceptions.